# Why does pressing tab to search Bestbuy.com to search in chrome turn into searching amazon.com?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I press tab to search bestbuy.com in my omnibar, it changes to amazon.com Why?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it got associated with Amazon site search as a keyword. Check under Chrome's settings.

Comment: check your  search engine settings AND answers in search (chrome://flags  > #answers-in-search)